# Best time, reason to leave according to Dhamma?

Tags: relationship, community

Say one dwells somewhere, somehow, enjoys or feeds on certain hospitality, at which occasion, at which point, it would be proper to leave and no more return?

So what's the time? Is time running out?

Koan-cracks also welcome!

Answer (score 0):

> Say one dwells somewhere, somehow, enjoys or feeds on certain hospitality, at which occasion, at which point, it would be proper to leave and no more return?

I think the best time to leave is when there's no more questions from the caretakers and when one has done whatever one could to repay the hospitality and make sure the caretakers are well and happy. Then one can leave and go to help others.